# No equals in Ordered trait in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

Ordered trait in Scala has various comparison methods like <,<=,>,>= etc.
But there is no method available for equality.
Is it a design issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly *not* a design issue.

If you check the source code for [`Ordered` trait](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/math/Ordered.scala), the implementations of all symbolic functions `<, <=, > and >=` are shortcuts to `compareTo`, which adheres to the Java convention for `Comparable` interface.

To check equality from the "ordering" point of view, you can use expressions like `compareTo(arg) == 0` or `compare(arg) == 0`.

I suppose that there is no symbolic shortcut for such checks in order to avoid confusions with *objects and references* equality (`equals()` and `==` from `Any`). Moreover, `def ==` is `final` in order to forbid it to be overriden.

Comment: "objects and references equality (equals() and == from Any)." This seems to imply `==` is reference equality, which is wrong. Reference equality is `eq`.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks for this remark. I agree, strictly speaking, reference equality is checked with `eq`. But both `==` and `equals` call `eq` under the hood anyway. I did not want to dig deeper into details here :)

Comment: No, `==` calls `equals`, and `equals`'s _default_ implementation calls `eq` but most don't (except for a quick return if it's true).

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's an issue, it's a minor one. You can always just import `math.Ordering`, and there will be an automatic implicit conversion from `Ordered` to [`Ops`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/math/Ordering$Ops.html), which provides an `equiv` method.

Simple example, an implementation of a method `e` that checks whether two elements are equivalent w.r.t. the canonical ordering:

```
import scala.math.Ordering

/** Checks whether `a` is equivalent to `b` w.r.t. 
  * the canonical ordering. */
def e[A <: Ordered[A]](a: A, b: A): Boolean = {
  val ord = implicitly[Ordering[A]]
  import ord._

  a equiv b
}
```

Since the `equiv` method is not provided after so many years, it seems that simply not enough people care about this issue. It just doesn't happen very often that `a equiv b` but `a != b`.

Answer (score 0):

This was intentional while designing scala. Because of type erasure, Ordered is not able to detect the type of the object which is needed to compare the equality of objects to be compared

Comment: Referenced from book Programming in Scala(unit: Traits, section: Ordered)